# How to Create JSON Array in Java

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a JSON structure as given below. How can I create this Array structure programmatically?

**JSON srtucture:**

```
{ 
"Employee": 
    [ 
      { 
        "EmP325235": 
          { 
             "Name":"Rekha_S", 
             "firstName":"Rekha", 
             "phoneWork":"788908909", 
             "lastName":"S", 
             "namePrefix":"Miss", 
             "phoneMobile":"3347687878", 
             "phoneHome":"5768900909", 
             "Email":"" 
          }, 
        "Em252555": 
          { 
             "Name":"Roopa_N", 
             "firstName":"Roopa", 
             "phoneWork":"0471245367", 
             "lastName":"N", 
             "namePrefix":"", 
             "phoneMobile":"", 
             "phoneHome":"", 
             "Email":"" 
      } 
      } 
    ], 
"User_Details": 
   { 
       "USER_ID":"7890", 
        "Number":"8585858585", 
        "Password":"Passwordsgs" 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations for a JSON library for Java?  There are lots at http://json.org

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use the [GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which will marshall Java objects.

There's an [array example](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples) to get you started, as well as a [ton of others in the user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Answer (score 0):

XStream provides a very convenient way to transform JSON to JAVA and back. Its annotation based and does the conversion job pretty well. Check [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

use the following link the complete structure of the JSON explained.

http://json.org/java/