# Elegant way for populating data in AlloyUI Data Table using JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, alloy-ui, scriptlet

I'm developing a `portlet` for a `Liferay` portal. I'm trying to use `AlloyUI` `Data Table` and my code is currently working, but they way in which I fear that I'm doing it in not an elegant and easy to maitain way.

Below is code from my `View.jsp`:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="com.mypackage.model.hpuc.Unit"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>Units Folder</b> portlet in View mode.

<%
    List<Unit> hpUnits = 
        (List<Unit>)renderRequest.getAttribute("hpUnits");
%>


<script>
var data = [

<%//loop through all but last because of the
//coma that shouldn't be added for the last element
    for (int i = 0; i < hpUnits.size() - 1; i++){ 
        Unit unit = hpUnits.get(i);%>
        { 
            description: '<%=unit.getDescription()%>',
            city: '<%=unit.getContactData().getAddress().getCity()%>', 
            name: '<%=unit.getRegistrationInfo().getName()%>'
        },  

<%} //close for loop 

    //add last element
    Unit lastUnit = hpUnits.get(hpUnits.size() -1);%>

    {   
        description: '<%= lastUnit.getDescription()%>',
        city: '<%= lastUnit.getContactData().getAddress().getCity()%>',
        name: '<%= lastUnit.getRegistrationInfo().getName() %>'
    }
]; //close data2 array
</script>

<div id="myDataTable"></div>

<script>
YUI().use(
  'aui-datatable',
  function(Y) {
    var columns = ['name', 'city', 'description'];

    new Y.DataTable.Base(
      {
        columnset: columns,
        recordset: data
      }
    ).render('#myDataTable');
  }
);
</script>
```

Problems that I see in this code are following:

1. Mixing scriplets with javascript code. It might be very confusing if
   code grows bigger.
2. Each label is declared 3 times (two times while
   populating data for table rows, and once for column labels). If one
   of the labels were to be changed, programmer might forgot to change
   it in any of those places.

Do you have any remarks about the way on how I could improve the quality of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, that is always better way to create data by portlet (java) and only the visualization put to the jsp. I know that is not so elegant to create JSON with java, but you can use various frameworks for serialization

Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/

XStream: http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

or create plain JSON with `org.json.*`
http://json.org/java/

see too [How to Create JSON Array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976643/how-to-create-json-array-in-java)

you can also put the column names to java path.

Comment: Before I wrote my question I thought about `Gson` but I didn't find then a custom property names via annotation feature that `Jackson` have. I'm still having some problems with adding it to my project but I tested it in some test project and it works great. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using servlets, where my JSON objects are created.

And in jsp, create a datatable which gets JSON data from servlet/portlet(in your case).

This way, I found it easy to control my GUI.

YUI datatable : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/