# Storing integers and arrays in a file and reading them

Tags: java, arrays, file, parsing, int

I want to store some integers and arrays into a file so i can let my program read and use them, but I have no idea how to do this.
I know that I can read single integers with a Scanner and save them to an array by iteration, but I would like to have a file like

```
Number=5;
Array={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

And my program should assign the numbers to it's variables automatically, like

```
int Number = file.get(Number);
int[] Array = file.get(Array);
```

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are plenty ways to do it, depending on how the data is stored in the file: binary data, plain text, from a specific format like XML or JSON...

Comment: Store it in a more structured format & use a library.

Comment: Regardless of what you use, you will have to write some part of the function `file.get` yourself. The closest thing to "automatic" you will get is probably JSON or some binary encoding.

Comment: Yes, I have already read about JSON, XML and Property files, but I did not really understand how to do what I want with them.

Comment: Start with Java Properties, write several test programs as simple as possible, each one doing the single thing. Repeat until you have better understanding. There's no other way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create JSON Array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976643/how-to-create-json-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using serialization. To store your information in a file, use a `FileOutputStream` and an `ObjectOutputStream` (from the java.io package), like this:

```
File saveFile = new File("filename.sav");
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
    try (ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut)) {
        objOut.writeObject(number); // you should use lower case for variable names
        objOut.writeObject(array);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

This will store your information in a binary file named "filename.sav". To get your integer and array from that file, use a `FileInputStream` and an `ObjectInputStream` and cast the retrieved objects to the desired type in the order they were stored in:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("filename.sav");
    try (ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
        int number = (int) objIn.readObject();
        int[] array = (int[]) objIn.readObject();
    }
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

This will also work for any serializable object (an object that implements `Serializable`).

Comment: Thank you, that should do it. Is there a way to write the file by hand?

Comment: By "by hand", do you mean storing the information to a plain text file?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write it down in an editor, my program does not to write the file.

Comment: If you want to write to a text file, do the same thing except don't use an `ObjectOutputStream`. Instead, just write your strings directly from the `FileOutputStream`.